# How do i show toast and title in new changed language in android

Tags: android

How do i show toast and title in new changed language in my android app.in my code,everything is working fine . but i cant update the changes for toast and title. 
My code is :

```
     - Changing the language in the application:

        public void changeLang(String lang)
        {
            if (lang.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
             return;
            myLocale = new Locale(lang);
            saveLocale(lang);
            Locale.setDefault(myLocale);
            android.content.res.Configuration config = new android.content.res.Configuration();
            config.locale = myLocale;
            getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            updateTexts();
        }

     - Save the current locale:

        public void saveLocale(String lang)
        {
            String langPref = "Language";
            SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("CommonPrefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putString(langPref, lang);
            editor.commit();
        }

     - Loading a saved locale:

        public void loadLocale()
        {
            String langPref = "Language";
            SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("CommonPrefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
            String language = prefs.getString(langPref, "");
            changeLang(language);
        }

     - Updating the UI elements of the current screen (you need to update only the screen in which a change of locale): 

    private void updateTexts()
    {
      setInterval.setText(R.string.btn_set_interval);
        tv1.setText(R.string.tv_nodata);
        tv2.setText(R.string.tv_nodata);
        tv3.setText(R.string.tv_nodata);
        tv4.setText(R.string.tv_nodata);

    }

     - Add events to the option menu. 

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            String lang = "en";
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.menu1:
                    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.cedesyn.com/"));
                    startActivity(browserIntent);
                    return true;

                case R.id.submenu1:
                    lang = "en";
                    Toast.makeText(this,R.string.toast_lang_en, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    changeLang(lang);
                    return true;

                case R.id.submenu2:
                    lang = "ru";
                    Toast.makeText(this,R.string.toast_lang_ru, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    changeLang(lang);
                    return true;

                default:
                    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onConfigurationChanged(android.content.res.Configuration newConfig) {
            super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
            if (myLocale != null){
                newConfig.locale = myLocale;
                Locale.setDefault(myLocale);
                getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(newConfig, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            }
        }
```

i can update the language of buttons and textviews by setText, But My Problem is how will i update the language of toasts.
     Can Anyone plz help me.

Comment: I'm curious, why did you want to handle yourself the locale ? You can easily localized your xml res files and let android choose the one adapted to the current local of the device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should export the string to the strings.xml located in a values folder specific for that country.

You will need to have a folder named "values-XX" where the XX represent the two letter identifier for the country in question (for eg: values-es, or values-fr). Inside of it you will place all the strings with the language specific translation in a new strings.xml. Now, in every strings.xml file, give same name for string but with different values(like `<string name="hello">Hello World</string>` and `<string name="hello">Bonjour</string>)`.

Finally, You can write following.

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.hello), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand what do u need exactly , but try to change the view ( toast or text view ) using UiThread,

example : `

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                         Toast.makeText(AddcarActivity.this, getResources.getString(R.id.yourmessage), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });
```